# Integral where upper limit is a dot - meaning?

Tags: integration, notation

Here's what I'm looking at (from [this book](http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf), page 14):

[image]

I get that the dot on top of $B$ is the time derivative - but what's that dot near the top of the integral?

Comment: This dot may be a placeholder for an upper limit. Without more context I cannot be sure.

Comment: If the $\cdot$ is a place holder, then it could be that the output is itself a function that places the input into the upper limit.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I've added a link to the original source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation

$$\int \limits _0 ^\cdot f(t) \ \Bbb d t$$

is a short-hand for the map

$$T \mapsto \int \limits _0 ^T f(t) \ \Bbb d t .$$

Concretely, you should interpret your formula as defining a map

$$(B,T) \mapsto \int \limits _0 ^T B^i (t) \dot {B^j} (t) \ \Bbb d t .$$

Comment: Shouldn't the full formula rather be interpreted as $B\mapsto (T\mapsto \int_0^Tf(t)\,\mathrm dt)$?

Comment: @celtschk: Fixed. I chose to "unlambda" your notation - in fact, this is what I meant to write in the first place, I somehow got confused on my way to doing it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - I was a bit confused when I first saw the answer, I must admit

Comment: @AlexM.: Actually you didn't unlambda, but uncurry the expression ;-)